# Dependecy Injection of collections

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection

I have a class `A` that works with `List<String>`. But nobody outside this class should need to know that it works with strings. However, I also want to supply the concrete implementation the class should use for it's `List` (via dependency injection).

`A` should look like this

```
public class A {
  private ListFactory listFactory; //this gets injected from the outside

  public A(ListFactory listFactory) {
    this.listFactory = listFactory;
  }

  public void a() {
    List<String> = listFactory.createList();
    //...
  }
}
```

And the caller class `B` something like this

```
public class B {
  public void b() {
    ListFactory factory = new ArrayListFactory(); //we want class A to use ArrayList
    A a = new A(factory);
    //...
  }
}
```

`ListFactory` would be an interface which is implemented by `ArrayListFactory` to create `ArrayList`s.

*Quintessence:*
I don't want that `B` has to mention `String` somewhere. And I also don't want that `A` has to mention `ArrayList` somewhere.

Is this possible? And how would `ListFactory` and `ArrayListFactory` have to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than you're making it, I think:

```
public interface Factory {
    public <T> List<T> create();
}

public class FactoryImpl implements Factory {
    public <T> ArrayList<T> create() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}

...
Factory f = new FactoryImpl();
List<String> strings = f.create();
...
```

Comment: Wow. Thx! I didn't even knew that syntax. Have to look that up... That's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Seems you wrote all you need. Factories will look like:

```
interface ListFactory<K, T extends List<K>> {
    T create();
}

class ArrayListFactoryImpl implements ListFactory<String, ArrayList<String>> {
    public ArrayList<String> create() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

class Sample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          ListFactory<String, ArrayList<String>> factory = new ArrayListFactoryImpl();
          factory.create().add("string");
      }
}
```

Comment: Thx! But that's not quite it, because the ArrayListFactoryImpl is implemented by the "person" who also implements class "B". And that person shouldn't have to know that class "A" needs Strings... Otherwise the user of class A has to know an implementation detail of A (that it uses Strings).

Comment: Could you pass factory to B from elsewhere, then?

Comment: The problem is that the factory currently knows about two things: Strings and ArrayList. And nobody should have to know about both these things, as one is an implementation detail of A and one is an implementation detail of B. But maybe it's not possible...

Comment: @qollin then just remove `K` type param from `ListFactory` and implementation and return raw `ArrayList`: generics are compile-time feature so it's impossible for A to enforce list to be `<String>` at runtime. Other way is to have wrapper over list passed from `ListFactory` that will check that all arguments to `List` methods are of `String` type (or any class passed to wrapper in ctor).

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt thanks to more clear understanding of the issue:

```
interface ListFactory<T extends List> {
    T create();
}

class ArrayListFactoryImpl implements ListFactory<ArrayList> {
    public ArrayList create() {
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}

class ListWrapper<T> implements List<T> {
    private final List impl;

    public ListWrapper(List impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    public boolean add(T t) {
        if (!String.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass()))
            throw new RuntimeException("Aaaaa");
        return impl.add(t);
    }

    // so on...
}

class A {
    A(ListFactory factory) {
        List<String> stringsOnly = new ListWrapper<String>(factory.create());
    }
}

class Sample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          ListFactory<ArrayList> factory = new ArrayListFactoryImpl();
          new A(factory);
      }
}
```